# How do I detect when I look away?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I make it so that Redstone will activate when I look away from a particular object? I am expecting command blocks to be used.
1.12+

Comment: Could you please specify which version of Minecraft you're playing on?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t detect players looking at blocks with command blocks(by objects I assume you mean blocks). But you could use a player detector e.g half block gap  with two blazes encased on the other side with a tripwire above them when they see a player they will fly up into the tripwire giving off a redstone signal.

Comment: You can use raycasting to determine which block someone is looking at, but in 1.13+. I'm not sure if it works in 1.12 and below but it is certainly harder.

Comment: Also, in 1.13+ a pufferfish detector is (in my opinion) better because there is less noise and space taken up, as well as it being invisible.